# Preview of polyline drawing each coordinate by coordinate in google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created an application in googlemap with poly-line, The application is working fine with the polyline drawn perfectly, But the problem is that i need to draw and show the preview of poly-line, drawing each coordinate by coordinate in google-maps

how can we achieve this? I have tried with setInterval(commented within my code) but its not working properly

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

```
      $scope.autoRefresh = function() {
    try {
      //
      routePoints = [];
      if (!_.isEmpty(items)) {
        angular.forEach(items, function(cordinates) {
          //setInterval(function ()
          //{           
            routePoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng));
            var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: routePoints,
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 2.0,
              strokeWeight: 3,
              editable: false
            });
            route.setMap(map);
            moveMarker(map, marker, cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng);
            markLAT = cordinates.lat;
            markLNG = cordinates.lng;
          //}, 1000);
        });  
      }
      //  
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vJflBqUQ5I4S0SGGEKP8?p=preview)**

Comment: What do you mean by showing preview of polyline?

Comment: are you wanto to show a marker within your polyline ? in each coordinate ?

like this picture ? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ggGbNf1fkRA/T-CBi2OHN2I/AAAAAAAAAIQ/SRdsFDuTLGQ/s1600/SC20120619-203658.png

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam now the marker is fine...only facing issues with the polyline drawing.....see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `setInterval` is not the right method, you must use `setTimeout`, otherwise the functions will run endless(until the browser will crash)
2. you must increment the delay for setTimeout, otherwise you will not see an animation(all functions will be executed with a delay, but at the same time...after 1 second)
3. don't create a new Polyline on each function call, you'll have a lot of Polylines at the end(1 for each item) . Create a single Polyline and push the locations to the path of the Polyline

   ```
   $scope.autoRefresh = function() {
   try {
     var route = new google.maps.Polyline({
             path: [],
             strokeColor: '#FF0000',
             strokeOpacity: 2.0,
             strokeWeight: 3,
             editable: false,
             map:map
           }),
           index=0,
           marker=new google.maps.Marker({map:map,icon:icon});

     if (!_.isEmpty(items)) {
       angular.forEach(items, function(cordinates) {
         setTimeout(function ()
         {         
           route.getPath().push(new google.maps.LatLng(cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng));

           route.setMap(map);
           moveMarker(map, marker, cordinates.lat, cordinates.lng);
           markLAT = cordinates.lat;
           markLNG = cordinates.lng;
         }, 200*++index);
       });  
     }
     //  
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
   }
   };
   ```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJaDgYQ6aPshHDboRdZF?p=preview)

Comment: hi....i have noticed one issue in your answer.............during the preview open another tab in browser and spend sometimee on it,....after sometime if you check the preview of the poly-line that is been been generated you can see some unexpected poly-lines drawn drawn along with the main poly-line........i am using chrome

Comment: I have posted a seperate SO for this [unexpected poly-line drawn along with the main poly-line in google-maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961977/unexpected-poly-line-drawn-along-with-the-main-poly-line-in-google-maps)

Comment: It's probably a mismanagement of the timeouts in chrome when you switch to the other tab(browsers usually try to save memory in inactive windows, e.g. by delaying the timeouts). I must go to work now, I'll take a look at it later.